# Prevent Matched data from being published using If statement in $each function

Tags: javascript

In this $each function I have json array data coming from a Ajax call.    What I am trying to do is; If the data coming from the ajax array contains the same unique name as the (current visible data to the online user. e.g in Divs classes) Alert it. That works it sends an alert.

The thing I want to do is prevent the data from going through after the alert if a match is found. I appriciate any help thank you. The alert is there to confirm match finding is working. I also use $grep so if the solution lies there I am happy to use that.

```
     Var data = [data from ajax]

     $.each(data, function( i, record ) {
     
     var getname = $(self).closest('.client').find('.name').html();
     if ( getname == record.name){
      alert("duplicate");
     }
```

Comment: So you're wanting to use the ajax data to filter out elements that are already in the DOM? When you say contains the same unique name, does this match to a div's name attribute?

Comment: yes filter out elements that are already in the DOM.  i  want to avoid duplicate Ajax posting, but if it occurs then I want to stop the data from ajax  poplulating all my div classes twice.  . I just selected  "name" as an example.   It could be a country, Surname,ID etc what ever I decide should be unique. I am a novice.

Comment: What do you mean duplicate ajax posting?  Is there more than 1 ajax call building the page?  Or is there duplicates in the ajax data itself?

Comment: I use just one script but there is more than one ajax call from the same script using a setinterval.   The setinterval first pullsdown all the data then 5sec later updates al the data.

Comment: Rather than messing with the DOM that much, it might be worth maintaining an array of IDs of the DIVs that are being added to the page.  As your do your data pull, see if the ID exists in the array and if not add the ID to the array and append the new DIV to the page.  This way you never have to worry about removing anything.

Comment: Thanks Phaelax ,  thats sounds like a positive way forward and a solution. Please  post this as your answer so I can give you a tick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than messing with the DOM that much, it might be worth maintaining an array of IDs of the DIVs that are being added to the page. As you do your data pull, see if the ID exists in the array and if not add the ID to the array and append the new DIV to the page. This way you never have to worry about removing anything.

```
var objects = {};

$.each(data, function( i, record ) {

    // Using the array to track records
    if (!(record.id in objects)){
        objects[record.id] = record;
        
        // create and add element to page
    }

    
    // OR....


    // Searching the DOM for the element
    if(!document.getElementById(record.id)){
    
        // create and add element to page
    }
}
```